# Windows 7 PC unable to connect to wireless router via USB

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have Windows 7, and I am trying to connect my PC to a wireless network. It doesn't have an internal card, so I use a Belkin USB stick.

Occasionally, my connection will just *drop*. It won't try to reconnect, and doing so manually will fail almost immediately after the "Attempting to connect [network]..." popup. After 20 to 30 minutes, it magically works fine again. This happens about 3 or 4 times a day.

I looked at the network adapter, and it always seems to fail at the "attempting to authenticate" part. I have removed the saved connection so that it prompts with my password, but it always fails at this same part. Most recently, it didn't even ask me for a password, it failed the second I clicked "connect".

Additionally, the system tray reports it as "Wireless Connection 4". I can't rename it to any lower numbers, as it says the network name already exists (and I've followed the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/470950/how-do-i-delete-previous-network-connections-from-windows-7?newreg=8ea901cbfd6a44dbbe8467b6ad8a8073) many times). *Sometimes*, the issue can be solved by removing the wireless adapter/driver and reinstalling it, but this takes time and a reboot, which is unacceptable for something that shouldn't even be happening.

The router is a Bell Netgear model MBR1516, with WPA2-PSK [AES]. We live in a rural area and have had many different wireless networks, and my PC has always had this problem. I do not think the router is at fault. Other devices can connect freely and have no issue.

Comment: Have you been able to try a wireless adapter from a different manufacturer (e.g. using a Netgear USB wireless adapter instead of the Belkin one)?

Comment: No, I haven't, as this issue is "recent" ... I've used this PC in other places over the last 2-3 years (college, sister's house) where they have a highspeed router physically connected to infrastructure; I would connect to that wirelessly with no problem. I am currently at my parent's house, and because of the rural location, we only have routers/hubs that connect wirelessly to the provider (via satellite or cell tower). We've had 3 or 4 different wireless models of this sort since March, and this PC just doesn't like them for some reason.

Comment: I have seen "differing" levels of compatibility in the past (especially Dell laptops to 3Com routers), so if there is one to hand, it may be worth trying.