# Windows 10 keeps appending a new sequence number to drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I keep having this issue with Windows 10 on both my laptop and PC. It only seems to happen with certain devices.

The issue is that Windows keeps adding a number to the driver every so often, like in this picture:

[image]

I only have one monitor connected, those are all the same device.

It's annoying and it is a hassle to fix. This post explains how to fix it by looking through and modifying driver registries: 
[How to get rid of auto-generated sequence number in network's device name in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/323331/how-to-get-rid-of-auto-generated-sequence-number-in-networks-device-name-in-win)

But that's a sketchy solution and it doesn't even stop the problem from reoccurring. How can I prevent this from happening?

On my PC it's happening with my monitor's audio driver as shown in the picture and on my laptop is happens with the built in audio driver.

I have 'show hidden devices' checked in Device Manager and it only shows the most recent version like in my picture, I don't see 1 through 5. And if I uninstall the driver starting with "6 - " it comes back again the same when I refresh.