# Identical USB NIC - how to distinguish/rename the adapter (by MAC, USB Port)

Tags: windows, networking, usb, batch

I have to connect to three different machines - which have the same IP adresses.

[image]
Engineering PC is Windows 7.
I am handling this some batch script, where the corresponding NIC is enabled and the other NICs are been disabled.

One NIC is builtin, the other two are identical USB NICs.
I just renamed them to **NIC2** and **NIC3**.

**But:**
As described [here](https://superuser.com/a/323338/1151303) or [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041110-00/?p=37343), it seems that windows is recognizing the same USB Device under different name - due missing Serial Number in the NIC.
The first one is plugged in - is always **NIC2**

I see two possible solutions.
Reassigning the name based on thei MAC-adress or based on their USB Port.

Question:
Can I assign/reassign/rename the NIC's based on the USB port, where they plugged in?
In Linux this can be done with [udev rules](https://askubuntu.com/a/50412) - In windows i did not find any solution.

Thanks.

Edit: [@gog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885175/14226613) explained it pretty well, how windows identifies USB devices .

Edit2: found an workaround with powershell, where you can enable/disable/rename a NIC per it's MAC-Address.
Anyway, I would prefer to do this per USB connection path.

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name * -Physical | where MacAddress -like "74-DA*" | Disable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$false
Get-NetAdapter -Name * -Physical | where MacAddress -like "74-DA*" | Enable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$false
Get-NetAdapter -Name * -Physical | where MacAddress -like "74-DA*" | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "MyNewName"
```