# Cannot delete corrupted registery key

Tags: windows-registry

I wanted to run `pip install` which is some python install-tool when I ran into an error regarding the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\{057C7771-F320-4C2A-A2EA-747945FA82F2}` (the program iterates over all keys in the `Classes` sub-tree).
When I try to open, edit, view its attributes, change permissions or delete the key with regedt32 (with admin privileges) a message box appears which reads: (summarized and translated from German)

Error opening key
Due to error the key [key name] can not be opened
Details: The system can't find the file

Doing a fast Google search I found that the key is somehow related to the application `Fast Picture Viewer` which in fact I had once installed. Does anybody know how to force delete that damn key? Thanks.

I found out that at least 5 other keys in the same directory show the same behaviour.

EDIT:

I found that the real key name is `{057C7771-F320-4C2A-A2EA-747945FA82F2}\0`

Comment: Did you try [editing the permissions](http://superuser.com/a/185828/23133) of that key and adding your account with Full Control, and/or taking ownership of it?

Comment: I am not able to change permissions, it tells me that there is no data available.

Comment: You are using an Administrator account and have ran regedit as an Administrator correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it [this way](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2021860):

You may get the following error message when trying to delete a registry key:

> "Error while deleting key"

This can be caused if you attempt to delete **a registry key that contains embedded null characters**. These characters are not visible when viewing the registry entry.
To delete a registry key that contains an embedded null character, you must first replace the null character with another character. You can accomplish this by using the **RegDelNull tool from Sysinternals**. This tool is available from the [following URL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897448.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your file that contains that part of registry is damaged.

There are many tools to repair registry. One is built-in in Windows (scanreg.exe).

Usage:

```
scanreg /fix
```

You need administrator rights.

If this wont help - look at duDE answer (about tool from SysInternals).

You may also run some [filesystem check](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/check-your-hard-disk-for-errors) and see loogs in [event viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer) to find out what caused your problem.

---

**Where HKEY_CURRENT_USER data is stored in Windows?**

From [Wikipedia (Windows Registry article)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry):

> The HKEY_CURRENT_USER key is a link to the subkey of HKEY_USERS that
>   corresponds to the user; the same information is accessible in both
>   locations. On Windows NT systems, each user's settings are stored in
>   their own files called **NTUSER.DAT** and **USRCLASS.DAT inside** their own
>   **Documents and Settings subfolder** (or their own Users sub folder in
>   Windows Vista and above). Settings in this hive follow users with a
>   roaming profile from machine to machine.

(`Documents and Settings` was renamed to `Users` in Windows Vista and later)